# Gzip not working for `fs.createReadStream`

Tags: node.js, gzip, zlib

For some reason gzip isn't being applied to my read stream, and I'm not sure why.

Here's the function I have written, `body` will always either be a stream from `fs.createReadStream` or just a raw string. The gzip will be applied if I pass in a string, but not when using a stream.

```
export function send(res, code, body) {
  res.setHeader('Content-Encoding', 'gzip');
  res.writeHead(code);

  if(body instanceof Stream) {
    body.pipe(zlib.createGzip());
    body.pipe(res);
    return;
  }

  body = zlib.gzipSync(body);

  res.end(body);
}
```

I get this error in Chrome:

```
ERR_CONTENT_DECODING_FAILED
```

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It should be `body.pipe(zlib.createGzip()).pipe(res);`, you are sending original stream